# is not assignable to type 'Observable<task>'.Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with Observable type, any idea?

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
    import {task} from './../models/taks.class'


    @Injectable()
    export class TaskService {
      public API: string ='http://localhost:3000/tasks'

      constructor(public httpservice: HttpClient){}
      getall(): Observable<task[]>{
        return this.httpservice.get(this.API)
      }
      add(task:task): Observable<task> {
        return this.httpservice.post(this.API,{
          title:task.title,
          co:task.co
        })
      }
      edit(task:task):Observable<task>{
        return this.httpservice.put(`${this.API}/${task.id}`, {
          title: task.title,
          co: task.co
      })
    }
      delete(id:number):Observable<task>{
        return this.httpservice.delete(`${this.API}/${id}`)
      }
    }
```

1. on the line `return this.httpservice.get(this.API)`

I am getting this

> error: is not assignable to type 'Observable'

I don`t know how to fix this problem

Comment: Can you show the model class?

Comment: import {task} from './../models/taks.class' In this instead of "task" it is "taks". Its correct only right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {task} from './../models/taks.class'    // confirm it is "task" or "taks"
@Injectable()
export class TaskService {
  public API: string ='http://localhost:3000/tasks'

  constructor(public httpservice: HttpClient){}


getall(): Observable<task[]>{
  return this.httpservice
         .get(this.API)
         .map((response: Response) => {
             return response;
         })
         .catch(this.handleError);
}

 private handleError(error: Response) {
     return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
 }

}
```

Comment: I don`t understand this your answer, you can explain it again, please ^^!

Comment: I don`t understand this your answer, you can explain it again, please ^^!, why do you use map((response: Response) => {
             return response;
         })
         .catch(this.handleError);
}. and  confirm it is "task" or "taks" .I put named wrong was taks instead of tasks :V akakaka

Comment: tks guy, i did it your way, but i still do not how to it works..add(task:task): Observable<task> {
    return this.httpservice.post(this.API,{
      title:task.title,
      co:task.co
    }).map((response: Response) => {
      return response;
    })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: When you are making an http request you have to follow some syntax. Try with this. In my app am following this way of request making and it is working fine !

Answer (score 0):

You should type your GET request.

```
return this.httpservice.get(this.API);
```

should be:

```
return this.httpservice.get<task[]>(this.API);
```